# Stop changing date value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Excel keeps changing my date to US format. I have a user form where the user inputs a date. As an example, I enter `01/11/2018` (1st November 2018). I then put this value into a cell however it changes automatically to `11/01/2018` or 11th January 2018.

I've so far tried using the following code to force it to use UK format;

```
SHT_data_TASKS.Cells(1 + tableRows, 8).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
SHT_data_TASKS.Cells(1 + tableRows, 8) = form_addTask_Date.Value
```

But it does not help. I've also tried using CDate function but still no luck. I've checked my computer regional settings and they are all correct for the UK.

If I right click on the cell where the date is placed and chose format it shows as already being formatted to UK date! I'm not sure what is causing it to change.

Comment: Is your PC set to the correct locality?

Comment: Yes all UK settings in control panel Region and Language

Comment: Dumb question - if you do `mm/dd/yyyy` does the date/month switch like it "should"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the date code I use on control containing UK dates:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.txtDate = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
End Sub
```

On the `AfterUpdate` event for the date control:

```
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()
    With Me
        FormatDate .txtDate
    End With
End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Public Sub FormatDate(ctrl As Control)

    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim IsDate As Boolean

    If Replace(ctrl.Value, " ", "") <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
            dDate = CDate(ctrl.Value)
            IsDate = (Err.Number = 0)
            Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

        If IsDate Then
            ctrl.Value = Format(ctrl.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Else
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Then I transfer it to the worksheet (on a Save button) using the below code:

```
shtRawData.Cells(rLastCell.Row, CLng(lCol)) = CDate(ctrl.Value)
```

Comment: This seems to have solved it - seems unnecessarily long winded just to get a date in the format it is typed but it is at least working - thanks!

Comment: It is a bit, but it tests that an actual date is entered to the control and changes the colour if it isn't.  Without the tests you could just use `cell = CDATE(ctrl.Value)` I guess.  I also make use of the controls `Tag` property to hold the column number to save to & dictate what kind of data can be entered to the control.

Comment: The answer given by @chilliin would be worth a look.  Haven't tried it on a form, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you're about to write your date to the sheet:

1. Verify that it's being stored as a date (or date equivalent) with `isdate()`
2. Assign it via `Range.FormulaLocal` instead of `value` or `value2`.

Untested, but i.e.

```
Range("A1").FormulaLocal = #10/31/2018#
```